# i can't import what is contained in a file into an object so i can use it in a JTable

Tags: java

```
Object data;
try {
    File file = new File("medicamente.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        int k = 0;
        for (int j = 0; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                data[i][k] = line.split(",");
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    fileReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it says: array required, but object found.
I want to read the file medicamente.txt and put everything in an object so i can put the object in a JTable.

Comment: Where does the compile error occur exactly?

Comment: in this line :  data[i][k] = line.split(",");

Comment: See David's answer, `data` is `Object` and not `Object[][]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, `data` is an Object (as you declared in your first line). You first need to declare it as `Object[][] data`.

You then need to initialize your values. You need to say `data = new Object[size][]` once you know how big 'size' will be (that is, how many lines you expect to parse).

Then for each line you'll need to say `data[k] = line.split(",");` - I'm assuming the '8' in your code is the number of comma-separated values that you expect in each line. You don't need to call `split` multiple times; one call with split the string and provide however many substrings are separated by commas.

Then, your call to `JTable table = new JTable(data, Object[] { "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8" } );` should be straightforward.

Comment: i solved that error using what you said and now, when i compile it says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at farmacie.Farmacie.handleMainPanel(Farmacie.java:100)
 at farmacie.Farmacie.<init>(Farmacie.java:38)
 at farmacie.Farmacie.main(Farmacie.java:163) and also in this line says : variable data might not have been initialized and when i click to initialize it gives me the same errors when i compile

Comment: data = new Object[20][];
     String line;
     int numLines = 0;
     while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      data[numLines] = line.split(",");
         numLines++;
     }
     fileReader.close();
  JTable table = new JTable(data, new Object[] { "col1", "col2" });

Comment: Where '20' is a guess about how many lines long your file is.

Comment: i don't get it, sorry. i have 8 columns. But i don't know where to put the lines wrote by you in the code

Comment: Replace everything you have between and including "String line;" and "fileReader.close();" with my code.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable data might not have been initialized
 at farmacie.Farmacie.handleMainPanel(Farmacie.java:108)
 at farmacie.Farmacie.<init>(Farmacie.java:38)
 at farmacie.Farmacie.main(Farmacie.java:157)

Comment: i have another question though, how can i do to have a checkbox  in the table and not the word true or false

Comment: That's another question for either further reading or another StackOverflow question :) See also TableColumn.

Answer (score 0):

`split` method returns `String array` .But you use `data[i][k] = line.split(",");` and data defined as object.So you should define data as String array than change this line with `data = line.split(",");` But vector is easy way to do this example code :

```
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    try {
        File file = new File("medicamente.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            String[] cells = line.split(",");
            for (String cell : cells) {
                vector.add(cell);
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>(); // you should fill colum names
    JTable jtable = new JTable();
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    jtable.setModel(model);
```

Comment: i have the comlumn names storred in a string: String[] columns = {"nume","compozitie","indicatii","contraindicatii","administrare","pret","compensabil","stoc"};

Comment: i tried what you wrote and it says:no suitable constructor found for DefaulttableModel(Vector<Vector<Object>>,String[])......argument mismatch, it's a pretty big list

Comment: you should write TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, new Vector(Arrays.asList(columns)));

Comment: it's not the columns i have a problem with, the word data is underlined with red

Comment: It is compiled successfully.

Comment: thank you for your time, i did it with the code from David, but i will be back soon enough to ask other stupid questions.